ReadTimeout during IOHandler.ReadBytes()
I am using Delphi 12.1 and Indy 10 on the client side and FreeRTOS 10 (Xilinx ARM53 on Zynq UltraScale) and LwiP on the server side. Only one client/thread is active.
I have the following simplified client code.
constructor TSocketThread.Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
begin
  inherited Create(CreateSuspended);
  FClient := TIdTCPClient.Create(nil);  // Create the TCP client instance
  FClient.OnConnected := FClientOnConnected;
  FClient.OnDisconnected := FClientOnDisconnected;
end;

procedure TSocketThread.Execute;
var
  Buffer: TIdBytes;
  RecIntegers: array of UInt32;
  MaxBlockSize: Integer;
begin
  while (not Terminated) do
  begin
    //connect client
    try           
      Synchronize(
      procedure
      begin
          Form_System_Log.MemoSystemLog.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', Now) + ' - ' + 'Connecting Ethernet');
      end);
      FClient.Host := '192.168.1.10'; // Set the IP address
      FClient.Port := 7; // Set the port number
      FClient.Connect;
    except
      for I := 1 to 5 do//wait 5sec to connect again and give room for a thread termination
      begin
        if Terminated then Exit;
        Sleep(1000);
      end;
      Continue; //try to connect again
    end;
    //start communication with server
    try
      FClient.Socket.ReadTimeout  := 3000;
      MaxBlockSize                := (4096*8 + 1024)*4 + 4;
      try
        while (not Terminated) do
        begin
          //--------------------------------------------------------------------
          FClient.Socket.Write(Generate_Sending_ByteArray(data_to_send));
          if FClient.Socket.CheckForDataOnSource(250) then
          begin
            // Method 1
            SetLength(Buffer, MaxBlockSize);
            FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, MaxBlockSize, False);
            //Method 2
//            SetLength(Buffer, 0);
//            while (length(Buffer) < MaxBlockSize) do
//            begin
//              FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, -1, True);
//            end;
           end;           
        end;
      except
        on E: Exception do
        begin
          Synchronize(
          procedure
          begin
              Form_System_Log.MemoSystemLog.Lines.Add(FormatDateTime('hh:nn:ss', Now) + ' - ' + 'Error Ethernet Thread: ' + E.Message);
          end);
        end;
      end;
    finally
      FClient.Disconnect;
      //Terminate;//close this thread
    end;
  end;
end;

If I use method 1 for reading:
SetLength(Buffer, MaxBlockSize);
FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, MaxBlockSize, False);

I get within 60min app runtime around 10 ReadTimeout exceptions.
If I don't terminate the thread, the thread tries to connect the client for ever (client can not reconnect)
If I use method 2 for reading:
SetLength(Buffer, 0);
while (length(Buffer) < MaxBlockSize) do
begin
FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, -1, True);
end;

I dont get ReadTimeout expetions at all but the thread gets stuck.
Q1: I wonder why, since both read methods should lead to the same results.
Q2: Is there a data/byte limit for the input buffer which could lead to a memory issue and the timeout?
Q3: If I use method 2, I dont get a ReadTimeout exeption but it seems that the ethernet thread freezes in a similar time interval as the occurance of the timeout in method 1, but the thread finishes "normal" after this lag. This lag is sometimes longer than the defined timeout. I wonder why, since no ReadTimeout occurs. Could this be just network lag, but then again, why no timeout?
Q4: I wonder why I have such a high traffic:

client to server traffic approx. 70kbytes/sec
server to client traffic approx. 2315kbytes/sec

since I wait on the client side through:
FClient.Socket.CheckForDataOnSource(250)

and the client sends 4096 bytes and the server sends 135172 bytes.
Apologies for so many questions

Asking multiple questions in one post is generally discouraged.  Try to keep posts as focused and direct as possible.

Thank you very much Remy for your explanation!
I checked the communication between the server and the client through Wireshark. All packages were send without errors and the server sends the expected number of bytes (no expections).
Nevertheless, I somehow found an alternative solution to avoid these timeouts by sending less bytes within one data stream. So the issue was on the serverside. Before, I was sending 135172 bytes at once. Now I send 20484 bytes at once.
I seems, that the TCPWindow was too long.
I was using (and still use) the settings recommend here:
LwIP Settings


If I use method 1 for reading ... I get within 60min app runtime around 10 ReadTimeout exceptions.

Then you need to debug your communication to find out what is going on at the network layer, and possibly increase your timeout.

If I don't terminate the thread, the thread tries to connect the client for ever (client can not reconnect)

If you can't reconnect, it means either the server is actually down, or moe likely Connect() is failing prematurely because Connected() is returning True if there is still unread data in the IOHandler.InputBuffer. You should be getting an exception telling you why the reconnect fails.
In an error situation where a session is not closed cleanly, you should empty the InputBuffer before reconnecting, just in case, eg:
FClient.Disconnect;
if FClient.IOHandler <> nil then
  FClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Clear;


If I use method 2 for reading ... I dont get ReadTimeout expetions at all but the thread gets stuck.

See below.

Q1: I wonder why, since both read methods should lead to the same results.

They are not doing the same thing.
Method 1 is performing 1 read operation, returning exactly MaxBlockSize number of bytes, no more, no less. If a timeout occurs, it means either the server did not send that many bytes to begin with, or the connection is not delivering the bytes fast enough.  Either way, this method will raise an EIdReadTimeout exception on a timeout as the requested amount could not be satisfied.
Method 2 is performing (potentially) multiple read operations, each one returning however many bytes are currently available (that is what passing AByteCount=-1 means), until you have collected at least MaxBlockSize number of bytes. Whether any bytes are read or not, each read is satisfied unless a true socket/OS failure occurs. So, this approach does not raise an EIdReadTimeout exception on a timeout, it will simply return 0 bytes instead. However, as you are not handling a timeout on each read, you can end up in an endless loop if no further bytes arrive.  Under this approach, you will have to check for a timeout manually, eg:
SetLength(Buffer, 0);
while (Length(Buffer) < MaxBlockSize) do
begin
  if FClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then begin
    if not FClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource(250) then Break;
  end;
  FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, -1, True);
end;

Alternatively:
SetLength(Buffer, 0);
while (Length(Buffer) < MaxBlockSize) do
begin
  OldLen := Length(Buffer);
  FClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, -1, True);
  if Length(Buffer) = OldLen then Break;
end;


Q2: Is there a data/byte limit for the input buffer which could lead to a memory issue and the timeout?

No. The InputBuffer grows dynamically as new bytes are read from the socket. It is limited only by available memory.

Q3: If I use method 2, I dont get a ReadTimeout exeption

See above.

but it seems that the ethernet thread freezes in a similar time interval as the occurance of the timeout in method 1, but the thread finishes "normal" after this lag.

That is normal behavior for that method's code.

This lag is sometimes longer than the defined timeout. I wonder why, since no ReadTimeout occurs. Could this be just network lag

It should not be significantly longer than the requested timeout. But, at the OS level, timeouts are not absolute, so there could be some slight overhead.

but then again, why no timeout?

It is timing out. It is just not raising an exception on a timeout, by design.

I wait on the client side through:
FClient.Socket.CheckForDataOnSource(250)

You are calling CheckForDataOnSource() only 1 time after each write.  That is fine for Method 1, which performs 1 read operation and a timeout is fatal to it. But it is not effective for Method 2, which performs multiple read operations where a timeout is never fatal to them.
